# Destroy associated objects in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-activerecord

I've got a rails application am building.
It consists of centers and students. A center has various days when it is in session.
A student belongs to a center and selects days they when they'll attend from the center's active days.
I've got a an association setup as shown below.
Destroying a CenterDay does not result in StudentDay being destroyed.

Please help

```
class Center < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :center_days, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :school_days, :through => :center_days
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_days
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :center
  has_many :student_days, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :center_days, :through => :student_days
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :center_days
end

class SchoolDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :center_days
  has_many :centers, :through => :center_days
end

class CenterDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :center
  belongs_to :school_day
  has_many :student_days, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :students, :through => :student_days
end

class StudentDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :center_day
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using ActiveRecord 'delete' method for destroying CenterDay object.
Use 'destroy' method to destroy your object, destroy method executes callback whereas delete method does not.

Example:

```
@center_day.destroy
```

Comment: CenterDay is destroyed when I update or destroy a center, not directly as you've put it. Or is there a way to destroy it directly when updating or destroying a center?